# Heisenberg's last work on a non-linear generalization of quantum mechanics?

Tags: reference-request, quantum-mechanics, heisenberg

It is claimed [here](https://youtu.be/I3zgWE8z8Cw?t=3274) that toward the end of his life Werner Heisenberg worked on a non-linear broadening or generalization of quantum mechanics. What work was that? Was it published?

Is it listed in Cassidy's [*Werner Heisenberg: A Bibliography of His Writings*](https://archive.org/details/trent_0116400254532)?

Answer (score 8):

This likely refers to Heisenberg's non-linear spinor theory of elementary particles, on which he worked from 1953 to the end of his life. There was a prominent write-up in an unpublished 1958 preprint with Pauli, from which Pauli withdrew his name. Heisenberg later gave a lecture [Quantum Electrodynamics in the Nonlinear Spinor Theory (1966)](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-61742-3_61) and published a book [*An   Introduction   to   the   Unified   Theory   of   Elementary   Particles*](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoun0000heis) (1967) based on his Munich collaborations with Durr et al. In the book Heisenberg proposes that all properties of matter should follow from a highly symmetrical field equation that plays a role of "Plato's form".

Heisenberg's publications are listed on [Academictree](https://academictree.org/physics/publications.php?pid=1932). The latest on the spinor theory is from 1974, [The unified field theory of elementary particles: Some recent advances](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00602885). Considering his health problems in 1973-6 it is unlikely that he worked much on it "in the last year", see [The Munich Years (1958 – 1976)](https://www.heisenberg-gesellschaft.de/7-the-munich-years-1958-ndash-1976.html), the 1975-6 publications are more historical/philosophical.

Here is [Todorov's description](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0503235):

> "*Heisenberg tries to build up a theory of a (not directly observable!) spinor field, which obeys a non-linear partial differential equation, with a coupling constant of dimension length square. The proton and the neutron, the building blocks of  the atomic nucleus, are not identified with the quanta of the basic field (as it is the case   with   electrons  in   quantum  electrodynamics), but  arise   as   its   bound  states. Heisenberg does not follow the beaten tracks (not even those that brought him success in the old days), he is looking for something really new...*"

> *In fact, Heisenberg is conscientious,that there are questions and “details”, which are not yet clear, but he is an optimist.For less emotionally engaged theorists the remaining difficulties and open problems set doubt on the whole enterprise. Shortly before his death later the same year (1958) Pauli   withdraws   his   name   from  their   joint   work   and  expresses   publicly   his disapproval. Heisenberg is affected and disappointed but he continues steadfastly his work (with his young collaborator H.P. Dürr). He works, like most great physicists of the  past   century   in   their   later   years,   in   virtual   isolation,  with   the  world   of   science ignoring his latest ideas.*

> *With   the  hindsight  of   subsequent   development   we  can   now  point  to   both   a prophetic vision and some shortcomings in this last attempt of the great scientist at anew breakthrough in fundamental physics... The quarks’ field in what we now call the standard model can be viewed as a realization of Heisenberg’s idea. (He discusses himself such a possibility after the first success of the quark model – some 10 years after his controversial 1958 paper.) In both cases the observable (strongly interacting) hadrons are bound states of the basic field whose quanta do not correspond to free particles. The idea of a spontaneously broken symmetry, associated today with the name of Higgs, plays a prominent part inthe Heisenberg model: it originates in his treatment of ferromagnetism of the 1930’s.The concept of a fundamental length is present in the now fashionable “superstring theory”...  Heisenberg   is   well   aware   of   the  non-renormalizability   of   his   model   but  he hopes that the gauge invariant equations of quantum electrodynamics will follow from his theory at distances large compared to the fundamental length.*"

Comment: Why did Pauli disapprove of Heisenberg's non-linear spinor theory?

Comment: @Geremia He got tired of Heisenberg's metaphysical infatuations, and his self-promotion in newspapers and on the radio. As he wrote:"*“What fascinates Heisenberg is also the mirror archetype... As a consequence of this fascination, he reproduces his obsessions over and over again and cannot listen to (or read) what others say*". See e.g. [Pauli's Ideas on Mind and Matter by Atmanspacher](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233554311_Pauli%27s_Ideas_on_Mind_and_Matter_in_the_Context_of_Contemporary_Science).

Answer (score 2):

As Conifold already mentioned, there were several problems with this initial approach: spinors where observable physical objects due to their dimension of $-\frac{3}{2}$, the introduction of a dimensioned coupling constant lead to non-renormalizability, etc. I have been following this topic for a while now and just recently came across this video proposing changes to this initial approach, leading to some quite interesting results. I think it is worth to watch:

[A non-linear spinor theory of elementary particles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDiuQqfVm3Y)